# Angular 13, receiving data from API, now how do I use it?

Tags: angular, typescript, state

I'm new to angular, making a quiz app to start learning in practice. I am currently getting a response back from the API with a random set of questions as intended, now I just need to figure out how to iterate over the array in that response to play the actual game. The idea is to render one question at a time and add to a running score if the correct answer is clicked.

I'm not necessarily looking for a full answer. The guides I've been using are just for simpler apps and I'm not sure what does/doesn't apply to my case, so a broad overview or just a couple next steps would be very helpful.

The query is being made in the 'parent' of the component where the question will be rendered, which is in turn the parent of where the answers will be rendered.

My experience is in React so I'm thinking in terms of saving state where the query is being made and prop drilling down to where the data will be rendered. I'm not sure how similar this is to Angular.

Here is my shared/services/api.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class apiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  apiURL = 'http://localhost:8080';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }),
  };

  getQuiz(category: any) {
    console.log('bacon');
    
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/quiz/' + category).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
}
```

The console.log(res) is working.

And here is my game-window.component.ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { apiService } from '../shared/services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'game-window',
  templateUrl: './game-window.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-window.component.css'],
})


export class GameWindowComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _apiService: apiService ) {
    
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService.getQuiz(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]);
  }
}
```

I'm also new to typescript in general so I'm not sure what kind of syntax I would even need to hard-save the expression in the ngOnInit()

Literally any information would help, even if it's just a list of steps in plain English so I know what to look for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in your case I would return the Observable instead of subscribe it in the **apiService**. And probably will subscribe to it in your component to wait for the answer.

**YourResponseType** will be the type of your response, the **httpClient** will be responsible of the mapping and returns you the object.

```
// API SERVICE
getQuiz(category: any): Observable<YourResponseType> {
console.log('bacon');

return this.http.get<YourResponseType>(this.apiURL + '/quiz/' + category);


}

// COMPONENT
ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService.getQuiz(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1])
.subscribe((response: YourResponseType) => {
   // You can assign your response to your component properties now

});
    }
```